How to get correct accents char within javascript on Ubuntu?
Surprisingly, this simply code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1> Keyboard input test</h1>
<script>
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    const pressedKey = event.key;
    console.log(pressedKey)
});
</script>
</body>
</html>

works differently on Windows and Ubuntu when you try to type an accents char like Spanish é or á using Dead key. On windows you will see 'Dead' first then correct char (é or á), but on Ubuntu you will get 'Dead' and then simple ascii char (e or a).
Looks like there is no way to get correct char in this case. I can't use input or textarea field in my particular task, so I wonder if it is actually so.
I can't believe that it is necessary to path the operating system just to achieve such a simple thing...

It'll also be different on MacOS, and who knows what phones will give you.

I figured out by myself that event keypress will do the work. That is fine for me, but still different behavior for seemingly standard things is weird.

Be aware that the "keypress" event is deprecated, and browsers may drop support at some point  (which, to be real, won't be soon).

That's a bummer. I.e. they deprecated a method without a working alternative. Nice!
